# as3 GIFPlayer displays incorrectly

Tags: actionscript-3, gif, bitmapdata

I'm using the GIFPlayer class that I found here:
http://code.google.com/p/as3gif/

The gif loads but not properly.

It shows all the frames in a sequence without removing the previous frame.

Therefore, by the end of all frames, I can see all the frames shown on the screen.

At this point all frames disappear and it all starts again. 
I should say that it behaves like that with 90% of the gifs I tried. 
It does work nicely with the other 10%, including the diego.gif that comes as an example.

Any advice?

Comment: You are using a project that has been dropped 4 years ago one of the issue: https://code.google.com/p/as3gif/issues/detail?id=10 is the same as yours and has never been fixed. The project source code is private and cannot be retrieved and fixed. Conclusion, to fix your issue don't use a project that has been abandoned 4 years ago.

Comment: thanks. Can anyone suggest a different way to load animated gifs using as3 ? A google search only yields the above irrelevant solution.

Comment: @MaorYichyeh BotMaster is partially right. I had a look at the repository and the zip contains the source code, therefore it can be fix. If it loads correctly but displays incorrectly my guess is some BitmapData objects aren't copied/drawn correctly (either wrong frame index or wrong coordinates) which should be in `org.bytearray.gif.player.GIFPlayer.as`

Comment: Thanks, George. I do have the source files, but I don't have the knowledge to fix them. Isn't there a different tool to load animated gifs using as3?

Comment: Found the source code yes. Should be fixable, my guess is that the bitmpaData is not correctly cleared and draw stuff on top of each other instead of getting rid of the last one drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of your particular issue, but try to use Flash-Animated-GIF-Library library. It is more current and is more optimized (used it in my project, gif decoding speed is greater).

[Flash-Animated-GIF-Library](https://github.com/Worlize/Flash-Animated-GIF-Library)

Comment: Thanks :) Can anyone post a quick example using this class? I can't find any.

Comment: The repo has test project. Everything is there.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Ingweland. Unfortunately, I'm quite an unskillful beginner when it comes to using these libraries. I was able to use the as3gif class that I mentioned in my first post here cause it came with a simple example. I really can't find any code example here. I can see it's referring to the mxml file as a usage example, but that's not for beginners. In the as3gif class all I had to do is to import the class, declare a variable of that type, make a url request and load the gif. 4 lines of code, that I could test in the actions panel of the flash pro.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Worlize/Flash-Animated-GIF-Library/blob/master/GifTest/src/GifTest.mxml) is direct url to the sample file. Indeed, this is flex file, but it has very basic example. This test app adds the functionality to navigate to the gif file, and then loads it contents. Just look at the actionscript portion. It's really basic.

Comment: Thanks again :) I do understand the as3 part in that file except I can't even get to make it compile in my flash pro. It doesn't know what the FlexEvent is (in spite of the import). How do I deal with that?

Comment: You should not copy/paste the whole code. You should only extract the part with GifPlayer.

Comment: I finally made it! Thanks for everything. Highly appreciated.